# edit_article_path how does this work in the Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in section 5.11 of [this rails 4 tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). I see this in my view

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
```

edit_article_path which goes to app/views/article/edit.html.erb
and i have a edit method in my article controller. Is this just Rails Magic (will it work in rails 3 too?)

Ie could i do foo_article_path(article) and it would redirect to a app/views/article/foo.html.erb and hit the foo method in my controller ?

I couldnt use this notation to redirect to a page from a different controller correct?

Comment: You can run `bundle exec rake routes` to see all of the routes and their names and controllers.

Comment: oh awesome @pdobb , so thats what rails give me out of the box right. to change the path of  edit_article GET    /articles:id/edit(.:format)   articles#edit, how could i call it say modify_article_path(article)? that would require a custom route right?

Comment: Yeah, the `resources` calls in the routes file gives you 7 default routes for each resource. You can make your own by adding to the those as found in the rails routing guide in nPn's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These helpers are created as part of the route definitions.  See the following for the details
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

For example you probably have something like

```
resources :articles
```

in your config/routes.rb file